# How to capture the process when login expires in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to trigger a method when the user's login expires, I'm using asp.net core mvc and uses built in login features. Is that possible in asp.net core?

Comment: What are you using to manage log in?

Comment: I'm using the built in from asp.net core web

Comment: Ya but which one? There are multiple options.

Comment: for Authentication, we are using individual user accounts and stores in the app

Comment: Have you configured app cookies?

Comment: not yet, i was looking for, if the login auth expires I can overwrite or modify it to call our custom methods.

Comment: Choose from one of these options, Session State, Temp Data, or cookies to keep track of session state. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1 Try to choose one so we can give you some better direction.

Comment: If you use cookies you can set the expire time.

Comment: i was exploring cookies, we i set the expire time. what i want to know is how can i know if the login was expired. Is there any built in functions to overwrite it?

Comment: What I sent was only a piece of the puzzle. https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html#id1 You can manage the state with middleware and serializing the `ISession` from the `HTTPContext` I'll try to look more into it when I get time. Sorry for not being involved much.

Comment: https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html#built-in-middleware